# Postgres server does not start

Tags: postgresql-9.4

Hello i am unable to start my postgres server. I got this error in my pg_log

```
2018-07-20 13:25:59 MUT LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-07-20 13:08:25 MUT
2018-07-20 13:27:27 MUT LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2018-07-20 13:27:27 MUT LOG:  redo starts at 3/550D86E0
2018-07-20 13:27:29 MUT LOG:  record with zero length at 3/58B66398
2018-07-20 13:27:29 MUT LOG:  redo done at 3/58B66238
2018-07-20 13:27:29 MUT LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2018-07-20 13:12:09.874+04
2018-07-20 13:27:52 MUT LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2018-07-20 13:27:53 MUT LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2018-07-20 13:27:53 MUT LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2018-07-20 13:33:53 MUT LOG:  could not open file "postmaster.pid": No such file or directory
2018-07-20 13:33:53 MUT LOG:  performing immediate shutdown because data directory lock file is invalid
2018-07-20 13:33:53 MUT LOG:  received immediate shutdown request
2018-07-20 13:33:53 MUT WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2018-07-20 13:33:53 MUT DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2018-07-20 13:33:53 MUT HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2018-07-20 13:33:53 MUT WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2018-07-20 13:33:53 MUT DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2018-07-20 13:33:53 MUT HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2018-07-20 13:33:53 MUT WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2018-07-20 13:33:53 MUT DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2018-07-20 13:33:53 MUT HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
```

This showed up in the log. I run a command in cmd:

```
c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin> .\pg_ctl.exe -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\data" start

server starting
```

And got this error in cmd

```
c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin>
2018-07-20 13:25:59 MUT LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
2018-07-20 13:25:59 MUT HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "pg_log".
```

In services also not running.

Comment: Your log says everything's fine.. is there any addtional data, like if you ever changed postgres ports? what kind of error do you get when trying to connect, how are you trying to connect (which client).. etc....

Comment: c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin> .\pg_ctl.exe -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\data" start
server starting

c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin>2018-07-20 13:25:59 MUT LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
2018-07-20 13:25:59 MUT HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "pg_log".

Comment: When starting server from command got this and in the services also when strating server does not start

Comment: The messages in your comment and the logfile both state that the server started just fine

Comment: It doesn't say it's not starting,